# POSTing JSON via AJAX to rails app throws invalid auth_token error, even if the api_key is supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, api, post

My Ajax call:

```
jQuery.post('http://acme.domain.vhost/objects.json',
            {object: data, api_key: "123"},
            callback_function);
```

that throws

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)
```

Which is weird, because when I do any request using CURL:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d '<object><name>Test API Object</name></object>' http://acme.domain.vhost/objects.xml?api_key=123
```

So.. what am I doing wrong here? I don't need an authenticity_token unless I'm posting a form via html and I'm not supplying the api_key.

what is really confusing is the last line in the console before the error is this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`api_key` = '123') AND (users.deleted_at IS NULL OR users.deleted_at > '2012-02-29 23:12:25') LIMIT 1
```

when I copy that into my database, it returns the correct user... 
So, why isn't the ajax request working?

UPDATE: 
Changed curl to POST so it is literally the EXACT same as the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's simply because you have `protect_from_forgery` enabled and you don't pass any `csrf_token` in your api call.

I generally avoid to derive my API controllers from `ApplicationController` for this reason: it's great to keep the `csrf` security but there is no use for it in an API.

Comment: but the curl command works just fine. curl even works for the same action objects/create. curl doesn't need a csrf_token. =\

Comment: in your curl request, you don't create enything, so there is no csrf issue

Comment: I will post example of a curl POST

Comment: also, the API controller IS the actual controller. I'm using restful authentication.

Comment: Did you let the 'protect_from_forgery' in your ApllicationController? Does your api controller inherits from ApplicationController? If not did you put 'protect_from_forgery' in your controller?

Comment: I shouldn't need to mess with that, because when the app receives a request from CURL, the protect_from_forgery stuff is ignored?  But yeah, all the controllers inherit from ApplicationController, which has protect_from_forgery